# Flutter Chrome Executable only works not with chromium

Tags: linux, flutter, google-chrome, chromium

i just have a question about Flutter on Linux with Chromium.

As far as i know, i need any Chromium based browser to run Flutter with it.
But after a fresh Chromium installation, Flutter didn't want to go with it.
So i decided to install google-chrome and then run Flutter -doctor

After that, Chromium was accepted.
Does anyone know how the installation of google-chrome affects a Chromium installation on Linux?

Comment: Not sure that it's correct, but as I know, `flutter doctor` check expected tools in their "default" locations. So flutter expects chrome to be installed on device in default location, otherwise user have to specify environment varialbe `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work without need to install Chrome

`export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=chromium`